# How do I use callbacks to order the chain of events in a command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a setup command, using the `#awaitMessages` listener 2 times in a row to set up a server correctly from a user input, but try as I might, I cannot achieve the effect of each message being sent, then collecting data, then sending the next message etc. Here is my code (I have removed lots of clutter you dont need)

```js
message.channel.send("Please enter the role ID of admin:").then(() => {

    const filter = m => m.content  

    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Admin role set up correctly')      
        }).catch(collected => {
                message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
        })
    });
    message.delete().then(async () => {
      await message.channel.send("Please enter the role ID of moderator:").then(() => {

        const filter = m => m.content  
    
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Mod role set up correctly')      
            }).catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
            })
        });
    })
```

What happens is the bot does not wait for my collect event, and just moves on to sending the next message e.g.

`Please enter the role ID of administrator`

`Please enter the role ID of moderator`

What am I doing wrong? - there is no error thrown (since I have not made a mistake in my code - it just does not do what I need)

Edit:

```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
          .then(collected => {
            if (!collected.content === "test") return;
              message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Admin role set up correctly')      
          }).catch(collected => {
                  message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
          })
          message.channel.send("Please enter the role ID of moderator:").then(() => {
  
            const filter = m => m.content  
        
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                  if (!collected.content === "test") return;
                    message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Mod role set up correctly')      
                }).catch(collected => {
                        message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
                })
            });
      });
      message.delete()
```

Comment: What is `callback` in your `.awaitMessages()` call?

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti I meant to remove that, apologies, that was me experimenting with callbacks (I looked them up on a doc)

Comment: No worries - also your filters that you use won't actually do anything. I would avoid mixing async/await and promises, I'd suggest picking one and sticking with it, for example `.delete().then(() =>{ channel.send().then(() => {}) });` rather than mixing your `await .send()`, especially as you seem to have chained await and also `.then()`? What I'd suggest in terms of logic is in your first `#awaitMessages`, you put your next message send and awaitMessages inside of the `.then()` of the first `#awaitMessages` if that makes sense.

Comment: ahhhh I think I see where you're going, I will try this

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti I believe I have done as you mentioned in the edit I just added, I trialled it and my bot doesnt seem to wait, I think I may have misunderstood you however

Comment: Your edit is nearly there, however you want the `Please enter the role...mod` and its `#awaitMessages` to be in your first `.then` with `collected`, you'll want to add a `.then(() => {});` to `message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Admin role set up correctly')` too.

Comment: @Pentium1080T That works in my head, thank you so much for the explanation - I will trial this now

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti You are a saint, this solved it!

Comment: Great! I will add an answer as this chain of comments may confuse some people!

Comment: Sounds good to me - thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would avoid mixing `await` and using a promise (`.then()`) on the same thing.

Also your filters aren't really serving much purpose as you just use an arrow function without doing anything with the result. You could fix this by limiting the filter so that only a specific user can trigger the `#awaitMessages` events by using the follow filter instead:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return user.id === message.author.id;
};
```

You also now only need to define this once, as it will be in the scope for the rest of the code now too

To fix the problem you're having, you can simply just chain everything together using `.then()`, whilst it might not be pretty, it works.

```js
message.channel.send("Please enter the role ID of admin:").then(() => {
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return user.id === message.author.id;
    };

    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
        if (!collected.content === "test") return;
        message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Admin role set up correctly').then(() => {
            message.channel.send("Please enter the role ID of moderator:").then(() => { 
                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] }).then(collected => {
                    if (!collected.content === "test") return;
                
                    message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: Mod role set up correctly');
     
                }).catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
                });
            });
        });      
    }).catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
    });
});
```

Note: I changed your filter to make sure the same user is always entering the commands.